# Java duplicate local variable. Stumped

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am brand new to coding and trying to get my second program working. It is pretty straight forward as to what it does, but it is throwing an error on line 24 "Duplicate local variable confirm". Can't quite work out why it doesn't like what I'm doing.

```
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);  
char confirm;

do{

System.out.println("Welcome to the story teller");
System.out.println("What is your name?");
String name = userInput.nextLine();

System.out.println("How old are you?");
int age = userInput.nextInt();

System.out.println("What country would you like to visit?");
String country = userInput.nextLine();

System.out.println("Great! So your name is" + name + ", you are" + age + "years old and you would like to visit" + country + "?");
System.out.println("Press Y to continue or N to start over");
char confirm = userInput.next().charAt(0);

  if (confirm !='y' || confirm !='n'){
 System.out.println("Sorry that input is not valid, please try again"); 
}
  else {
  System.out.println(name + "landed in" + country + "at the age of" + age + ".");
  }
} while(confirm == 'Y'|| confirm == 'y');
```

Comment: you declared char confirm two times within the same (local) scope. either remove the line char confirm; or turn the line char confirm = userInput.next().charAt(0); in confirm = userInput.next().charAt(0);
I would recommend the second.

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring `confirm` twice. Change the second declaration to just assigning to it and you should be OK:

```
confirm = userInput.next().charAt(0);
// No datatype, so you aren't declaring confirm, just assigning to it
```

Comment: Thanks heaps! Would have taken forever to find that

Answer (score 1):

Because your "confirm" variable already defined in the scope (second row). If you want to assign a value, just write `confirm = userInput.next().charAt(0);`

Answer (score 0):

Another option to fix is to remove the unnecessary declaration `char confirm;`

And use it only when needed

```
char confirm = userInput.next().charAt(0);
```

As @ScaryWombat suggested, you will need to change scope of the variable (currently `while` is in different scope than `do` )

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems apart from re-declaration of the variable `confirm` there are one or  more issue -

> Issue 1:

After `int age = userInput.nextInt()`. It won't prompt for country input and will prompt `Press Y to continue or N to start over`.

*Cause of this issue:*

Since you are using `int age = userInput.nextInt();` the scanner will only take the integer value from the input and will skip the `\n` newline character.

*Fix*

As a workaround, I've added `userInput.nextLine();` after `int age = userInput.nextInt();` such that it will consume the `\n` character after `nextInt()`.

> Issue 2:

**After the 1'st iteration**, this line will cause issue`confirm = userInput.next().charAt(0);`.

*Cause of this issue:*

In **2'nd iteration** you won't get a prompt to enter the name as the line `String name = userInput.nextLine();` will take `\n` from the last iteration as input and will skip and prompt for age `How old are you?`.

*Fix*

As a workaround, I've added `userInput.nextLine();` after `confirm = userInput.next().charAt(0);` such that it will consume the `\n` character after `userInput.next().charAt(0)` and the next iteration will go as expected.

> Issue 3:

This logic `if (confirm !='y' || confirm !='n')` expects only `y` and `n` in `lowercase` but here `while(confirm == 'Y'|| confirm == 'y')` you are expection `y` and `Y` both.

*Fix* - I've added the necessary changes in the code below but would recommend you do change it to a switch case.

**NOTE:**

> It is not recommended to do `userInput.nextLine()` after every input and you could simply parse it. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13102066/6090738) for further information.

*I'm not recommending it but this will get you program working*

```
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    char confirm;

    do {

        System.out.println("Welcome to the story teller");
        System.out.println("What is your name?");
        String name = userInput.nextLine();

        System.out.println("How old are you?");
        int age = userInput.nextInt();

        userInput.nextLine(); //adding this to retrieve the \n from nextint()

        System.out.println("What country would you like to visit?");
        String country = userInput.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Great! So your name is " + name + ", you are " + age
                + "years old and you would like to visit " + country + " ?");
        System.out.println("Press Y to continue or N to start over");
        confirm = userInput.next().charAt(0);

        userInput.nextLine(); //adding this to retrieve the \n this will help in next iteration

        System.out.println(name + " landed in " + country + " at the age of " + age + ".");

        if (confirm == 'y' || confirm == 'Y') {
            continue; // keep executing, won't break the loop
        } else if (confirm == 'n' || confirm == 'N') {
            break; // breaks the loop and program exits.
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry that input is not valid, please try again");
            // the program will exit
        }
    } while (confirm == 'Y' || confirm == 'y');
}
```

> Recommending that you use switch case instead of if comparasion of `confirmation` and parse the character and integer input and remove the arbitary `userInput.nextLine()` added as workaround.